# React lags during multiple functional calls

Tags: reactjs

I followed this youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpLN1Kpd32M&t=9s
But made few changes like, I am calling `handleEmojiClick` using useEffect for 2 sec showing multiple icons on screen

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCount(true)
      localStorage.animate = false;
    }, [2000])
    if (count == false && localStorage.animate == "sign out") {
      handleEmojiClick("label", "");
    }
  });
```

But now the problem is that this animation lags a bit. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect probably requires dependencies like

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCount(true)
      localStorage.animate = false;
    }, [2000])
    if (count == false && localStorage.animate == "sign out") {
      handleEmojiClick("label", "");
    }
  },[someDependency]);
```

So that something triggers is to go. You can also have a `[]` as a dependency to fire it off on componentdidmount